# How to maintain order of class members and still have a working constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I want to have tidy header files, where puiblic members are listed first, then private members.

```
class A
{
public:
    A() : y(0), z(0), x(y + z)
    {}

    int x;

private:
    int y;
    int z;
};
```

Members are initialized in the order they are declared, so this constructor is buggy because y and z are not initialized when x is using them.

This is just an example where I could write x(0), but if these weren't ints but bigger types, then it would be cumbersome.
To get around this I would need to first list privete members y and z,
then public member x.
Is there any way that I can leave my private members at the bottom whilst initializing them first in the initializer list?

If not, please guide me to how I should order members, because I can't find any examples of this online. First listing some public, then some private, then more public members seems dirty to me but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: The simple way is to not have members rely on each other.  Having them do so makes the code brittle and more prone to bugs.

Comment: Why not declaring `x` as zero and use the constructor to add `y` and `z` ?

Comment: your example isnt the best. For this specific example the fix would be to simply initialize `x(0)`, no reason to make it more complicated than necessary

Comment: also note that c++11 introduced delegating constructors, i never used them myself, but I would guess that they help to circumvent the problem

Comment: You can move y,z to a private base.

Comment: Do you need an `x` value? Or can it just be calculated on demand via `GetX()` method?

Comment: You could use "in-class initialization"; `int x{0};` in the class declaration rather than the constructor initialization list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++, as a language, doesn't do a great job of keeping implementation details out of header files, or separate from the interface in general. Anything you do here is going to be a compromise.

One hard-line approach would be to not have any public member variables, and for that matter to separate and expose a pure virtual interface (in a separate file). At that point, the actual class wouldn't even need to be in a header -- just in a source file, referred to by a factory function -- so the remaining header is as clean as you'd like. This is not an approach I'd recommend.

In any case, there are various practical considerations in C++ which constrain the order of class members. Putting all the public members at the top of the class is a good plan A, but sometimes it's not going to work out, and I wouldn't suggest that you go to any heroics to make it work out.

Answer (score 4):

Using a delegating constructor you can write this as:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() : A(0, 0) { }
    {}

    int x;

private:
    explicit A(int y_, int z_) : x(y_ + z_), y(y_), z(z_) { }
    int y;
    int z;
};
```

Comment: This is a good way to solve the problem as stated, but I just want to observe that classes that mix and match public data (no invariants can be supported) and private data (class interface enforces invariants) will make classes somewhat to significantly harder to read/maintain in the future.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way that I can leave my private members at the bottom whilst initializing them first

No. Members are initialised in order of declaration; there is no way around that.

If you just want the members somewhere other than the top of the class, then you could use a base:

```
struct B {
    int y;
    int z;
};


class A : B
{
public:
    A() : B{0, 0}, x(y + z)
    {}

    int x;
};
```

> First listing some public, then some private, then more public members seems dirty to me but maybe I'm wrong.

That's not necesasry in your case, as you can put all private stuff first and then all public. But in general, splitting declarations with same access specifier is just fine; although rarely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that X is dependent on Y and Z, but Y and Z are knowns.
Possible ways you could look to solve this:

(1) Pass in a constructed X, instead of having the constructor make it.

```cpp
int y = 1;
int z = 40;
int x = y + z;
A(y, z, x);
```

(2) A more wild idea, (please don't do this, it typically indicates a problem with how you've factored your code).  Create a default object and then use placement new.   However, when I see code like this, it's typically using an `init()` function or something.  It's super overkill for ints, but I'm assuming that you have a more complex type which is why you're doing it.

```cpp
A() : y(0), z(0), x(/*default construct*/)
{
  new (&x) int(y + z);
}
//or
A() : y(0), z(0), x(/*default construct*/)
{
  x.init(y, z);
}
```

Overall, I think you should re-evaluate why X depends on Y and Z, and maybe shuffle some data and responsibilities around.

If X depends on the state of Y and Z, you might want to make it a function instead if it's used outside of the class, because as a public member variable other people could modify it and possible de-sync it from X and Y.  You might also want to put Y and Z inside of X instead.

Comment: That's what delegating constructors are for. Using in-place new is dirty.

Comment: Hence my warning.  In-place new in general outside of a memory manager or buffering system in general indicates a severe problem somewhere.

Comment: I'm 99% sure that `x` in this case should just be a calculated value, or y and z belong in x with possible accessors.  Without seeing the actual code I don't know for sure though.